# Best way to transform text into number in a big array

Tags: code-review

I have a big array of data that I imported from a lot of XML files. To get the data, among other manipulations,  I use this function:

```
Cases[xml,XMLElement[nodeName,_,a_]-> a,\[Infinity]]
```

When I get my final array, I have a lot of number fields that are as `String` and that I need to convert into `Number`. To do that I created this function:

```
clean[data_]:=Map[If[NumberQ@ToExpression[#],ToExpression[#],#]&,data,{-1}]
```

The problem is that I have strings with "??" characters, so if o use `clean` on it as for example:

```
clean[{"asd??asd", "123.3"}]
```

Mathematica try to interpret the first element as context ones. And I get:

```
Global`asd
```

How to avoid it? How can I improve my `clean` function, or the way I load de XML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than applying `ToExpression` and then `NumberQ`, perhaps you could just use `StringMatchQ` with `NumberString` in the first place.

```
StringMatchQ["assd??asd", NumberString]
(* Out: False *)

StringMatchQ["123.3", NumberString]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Nice! Will try it. Nice tip.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Tks